# adding average line group by column in r

Tags: r, group-by, average, geom-point

hi i have data that looks like this :

[image]

38 columns total . 10 types of treatments in treatment column and dates from 25-29 in date column data sample code ( example for 2 treatment types but the data has 10 types ):

```
df <- structure(
    list(
      Christensenellaceae = c(
        0,
        0.009910731,
        0.010131195,
        0.009679938,
        0.01147601,
        0.010484508,
        0.008641566,
        0.010017172,
        0.010741488,
        0.1,
        0.2,
        0.3,
        0.4),
      Date=c(25,25,25,25,25,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27),
      Treatment = c(
        "Original Sample",
        "Original Sample",
        "Original Sample",
        "Original Sample",
        "Original Sample"
        "Treatment 1",
        "Treatment 1",
        "Treatment 1",
        "Treatment 1",
        "Treatment 2",
        "Treatment 2",
        "Treatment 2",
        "Treatment  2")
    ),class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-9L)
  )
```

what i whish to do is to create 2 plots for every column one for Original treatment and other for the all the treatment types (1-10) in example here (1-2)  and add mean lines of the observations based on every treatmment type . in total the treatment plot should have 10 average lines ( here 2) . sadly i dont understand how to add the line grouped by the treatment types
here is my code for the one line based on all treatment types . how  can i add the line grouped by treatment type :

```
df_3 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-treatment) %>% 
  mutate(plot = ifelse(str_detect(treatment, "Original"), 
                       "Original sample", 
                       "Treatment"),
         treatment = str_extract(treatment, "\\d+$")) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map(~.x %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(treatment), y = value, color = factor(name))) +
        geom_point() +
        stat_summary(aes(y = value,group=1), fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line",group=1)
        +
        facet_wrap(~plot, scales = "free_x") +
        labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Value", color = "Taxa") +
        guides(x =  guide_axis(angle = 90))+
        theme_bw())
```

[image]
as you can see there is only one  mean line and i need 10 ( here 2 ) for every treatment type . is there any way to edit my code so it will work ? thank you:)

Also  I tried this code but I didn't seem to work

```
      df %>% 
     pivot_longer(-c(Treatment, Date), names_to = "taxon") 
      %>% mutate( type = Treatment %>% str_detect("Original") 
      %>% ifelse("Original", "Treatment"), treatment_nr = Treatment 
       %>% str_extract("(?<=Treatment )[0-9]+") )
         %>% ggplot(aes(Date, value, color = treatment_nr)) + 
           geom_point() + stat_summary( geom = "point", fun.y = 
           "mean", size = 3, shape = 24 ) + geom_line() + facet_grid(type 
            ~ taxon, scales = "free_y") #> Warning: `fun.y` is deprecated. 
                Use `fun` instead.
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up with your data and description. There's more going on here than just the mean line. `str_extract` is taking only the date, not the treatment number (and you're plotting the date). Did you want to plot the treatment or the date?

Comment: The plot pic for example is only for treatment 1 my code worked well for doing so for all the columns in the data . But I need this plot to have all the  10 average lines for each treatment (10   in my data but there are 2 in data code sample ) so basically the plots I wish have the date on the x line as seen in the pic and all the average lines each line for each treatment type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data wasn’t formatted properly and didn’t match up with your original sample code (e.g. `Treatment` instead of `treatment`). I’m going to generate some data here instead anyway for the purpose of illustrating the solution based on the data in your image.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <-
  data.frame(
    Christensenellaceae = runif(105),
    treatment = rep(c("Original Sample_25", 
                      paste0("Treatment", 1:10, "_", 27), 
                      paste0("Treatment", 1:10, "_", 28)), 
                    each = 5)
  )
```

Because you’re generating the mean as a line it will connect on the x-axis. I’ve done a pretty lazy work around using a segment and calculating the mean prior to the plot. Depending how it looks with your ten treatments, you can change the size of the average line by changing `avg_line_length`.

Because there are additional x-axis values with the segment (e.g. 0.65, 1.35), the x-axis would default include those additional values. I’ve created labels and breaks to address that and I've used the intermediate data `labs_df` for that. I’ve left the original blank. You could play around with color/linetype to display the line as 'Mean' in the legend as well.

```r
avg_line_length <- 0.35

p <-
  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-treatment) %>% 
    mutate(plot = ifelse(str_detect(treatment, "Original"), 
                         "Original sample", 
                         "Treatment"),
           treatment = as.numeric(str_extract(treatment, "\\d+")),
           treatment_label = ifelse(plot %in% "Original sample", "", treatment)) %>% 
    {. ->> lab_df} %>%
    group_by(treatment) %>%
    mutate(avg = mean(value),
           xstart = treatment - avg_line_length,
           xend = treatment + avg_line_length) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    group_split() %>% 
    map(~.x %>% ggplot() +
          geom_point(aes(x = treatment, y = value, color = name)) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = xstart, xend = xend, y = avg, yend = avg, color = name)) +
          scale_x_continuous(breaks = lab_df$treatment, labels = lab_df$treatment_label) +
          facet_wrap(~plot, scales = "free_x") +
          labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Value", color = "Taxa") +
          guides(x =  guide_axis(angle = 90))+
          theme_bw()) 

p
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

And if you don’t want the average line for the original sample, just an additional `ifelse`.

```r
p2 <-
  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-treatment) %>% 
    mutate(plot = ifelse(str_detect(treatment, "Original"), 
                         "Original sample", 
                         "Treatment"),
           treatment = as.numeric(str_extract(treatment, "\\d+")),
           treatment_label = ifelse(plot %in% "Original sample", "", treatment)) %>% 
    {. ->> lab_df} %>%
    group_by(treatment) %>%
    mutate(avg = ifelse(plot %in% "Original sample", NA, mean(value)),
           xstart = treatment - avg_line_length,
           xend = treatment + avg_line_length) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    group_split() %>% 
    map(~.x %>% ggplot() +
          geom_point(aes(x = treatment, y = value, color = factor(name))) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = xstart, xend = xend, y = avg, yend = avg), colour="red") +
          scale_x_continuous(breaks = lab_df$treatment, labels = lab_df$treatment_label) +
          facet_wrap(~plot, scales = "free_x") +
          labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Value", color = "Taxa") +
          guides(x =  guide_axis(angle = 90))+
          theme_bw()) 

p2
#> [[1]]
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

It's messy, but hopefully that addresses your problem.